# Revisiting Old Code- AI (Can't get it to work)

Tags: python, machine-learning, module

I went to an AI coding camp a few years back, and we worked in python to learn about machine learning. I have a bunch of .py files of them but can't get them to run. I put the code into PyCharm and tried to run, but it said I have missing libraries. Code:

```
from skimage import transform
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory)
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f)
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "/home/student/Downloads"
train_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Testing")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)

traffic_signs = [300, 2250, 3650, 4000]


plt.show()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the unique labels
unique_labels = set(labels)

# Initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

# Set a counter
i = 1
# Rescale the images in the `images` array
images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]

# Convert `images28` to an array
images28 = np.array(images28)

   # Convert `images28` to grayscale

    images28 = rgb2gray(images28)
    # For each unique label,
    for label in unique_labels:
        # You pick the first image for each label
        image = images[labels.index(label)]
        # Define 64 subplots
    plt.subplot(8, 8, i)
    # Don't include axes
    plt.axis('off')
    # Add a title to each subplot
    plt.title("Label {0} ({1})".format(label, labels.count(label)))
    # Add 1 to the counter
    i += 1
    # And you plot this first image
    plt.imshow(image)





for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images28[traffic_signs[i]], cmap="gray")
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(images28[traffic_signs[i]].shape,
                                                  images28[traffic_signs[i]].min(),
                                                  images28[traffic_signs[i]].max()))
    # Show the plot


# Import `tensorflow`
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])

# Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)

# Fully connected layer
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)

# Define a loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y,
                                                                logits = logits))
# Define an optimizer
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

# Convert logits to label indexes
correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)

# Define an accuracy metric
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(201):
    print('EPOCH', i)
    _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: images28, y: labels})
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print("Loss: ", loss)
    print('DONE WITH EPOCH')
sample_indexes = random.sample(range(len(images28)), 10)
sample_images = [images28[i] for i in sample_indexes]
sample_labels = [labels[i] for i in sample_indexes]

# Run the "correct_pred" operation
predicted = sess.run([correct_pred], feed_dict={x: sample_images})[0]

# Print the real and predicted labels
print(sample_labels)
print(predicted)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(len(sample_images)):
truth = sample_labels[i]
prediction = predicted[i]
plt.subplot(5, 2,1+i)
plt.axis('off')
color='green' if truth == prediction else 'red'
plt.text(40, 10, "Truth:        {0}\nPrediction: {1}".format(truth, prediction),
         fontsize=12, color=color)
plt.imshow(sample_images[i],  cmap="gray")
plt.show()
test_images, test_labels = load_data(test_data_directory)

# Transform the images to 28 by 28 pixels
test_images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in test_images]

# Convert to grayscale
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
test_images28 = rgb2gray(np.array(test_images28))

# Run predictions against the full test set.
predicted = sess.run([correct_pred], feed_dict={x: test_images28})[0]

# Calculate correct matches
match_count = sum([int(y == y_) for y, y_ in zip(test_labels, predicted)])

# Calculate the accuracy
accuracy = match_count / len(test_labels)

# Print the accuracy
print("Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy))
```

So I know some other things (like directories of the files) are different because I used their computer for the camp. I can fix that. However, I can't figure out how to fix the "missing module" problems.
Error code-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Eric/PycharmProjects/Cartpole1/Try1.py", line 2, in <module>
        from skimage import transform
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

as well as many others like it. Do I need to download something, or is the code not quite right? I remember the code working when I downloaded it to the usb drive i'm using.

Comment: I would highly suggest that you review Python basics before dealing with code like this. There are many free tutorials, books etc. out there. No offense meant, buy you will run into _many_ issues if you don't even know how to install libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the correct PM's (package managers) so all your import statments you have you need to make sure you have those libraries installed on your system or reference them here's a link to show you how to do that basically at the top everywhere you have an import statement make sure you have that library installed

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: you can also install them in command line through your terminal by using pip